# @import syntax in Angular

Tags: angular

In `styles.css` the following statement will load bootstrap css, provided that it is npm installed ..

`@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"`

on the other hand

`@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');`

can be placed on the component level into the file referred by `styleUrls` and it works, but it does not work if replaced by 1st @import statement that takes css from node_modules....

Is there a way to load css (e.g. bootstrap.min.css) placing it into `/app.component.css`  of component `styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']` from node_module folder similar to `@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"`I can not figure out the syntax..  Thanks.

Comment: And why exactly would you want to do that?

Comment: @import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"; this works for app.component.css as well.

Answer (score 0):

1. I need it because in some countries CDN are not accessible.. so I have to have all on our server..
2. Somehow the "~.. does not work when in the component's css.. but work only in  root styles.css, when it is global.. I would think that reference should have different syntax..